# MITM script error \Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\mitmproxy: No such script: save_website_source.py

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I'm currently working on a python script for our Project in Project Management that will save the source code of a website when a user accesses it in order to parse through the HTML source file to identify different indicators of a phishing website. This script is meant to run in the background so that our extension can continue with the rest of its processes. Currently, I am trying to use mitmproxy in python in order to listen for HTTPS requests so that the user's device can save the respective source file.

This is where the problem arises, when I try to run the script in my command prompt, I am met with this error. `Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\mitmproxy: No such script: save_website_source.py.` First, I attempted to save the script to this path, but I was met with the error that this path does not exist. When I try to search for this path in my file explorer the file explorer gets stuck loading.

Do you know if there is any way I can run this script by first specifying the path where the script resides or if there is a way to save my script to the desired path?

Comment: **Please edit your question** and include the command you use for executing mitmproxy including all arguments. Also please add details about your OS.